# SwiftUI: how to reapply ForEach filter on calendar day change?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have an app which shows a list of CoreData entries. I need to show random items and change the list once a day with a different set of random items. I use a filter to pick items I need to show today:

```
ForEach(items.filter{ myFilter(item: $0)} ) { item in
```

My Filter code:

```
    func myFilter(item: Item) -> Bool {

    if !settings.lastUpdatedDate.isInToday { //checks if items list is up to date
        changeTodayItems() 
        settings.lastUpdatedDate = Date() //logs a new update date after list refresh completion
    }

    return item.isToday //returns true if item should be in todays list
}
```

However, the list won't auto update when a calendar day changes. I want list to update at 00:00:00 but nothing happens until I relaunch an app or add a new item to the list. How should I trigger list to reapply the filter on calendar day change?

Comment: would u add re-produciable code

Comment: You need to trigger a notification or similar when a new day starts

Comment: This is not a SwiftUI level task, you need to do this at engine level, and ... I assume you use @FetchRequest wrapper, so it does not fit either here, because refreshed only on model changes, which is not the case here, so you need manual fetch request to be forced once engine detects and notifies day changed.